# Wordpress Variation Swatches for WooCommerce Selected item tick mark

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using WordPress Variation Swatches for WooCommerce plugin to show variations on my product page that offers me to change background color when an item is selected.

The plugin offers to change selected variations background-color but I would like to remove background and have a checkmark on the right top of the item when selected.

Here is the CSS code of that plug I am using.

```
    <?php
    defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'Keep Silent' );
?>
<style type="text/css">
    .wvs-archive-variation-wrapper .variable-item:not(.radio-variable-item) {
        width  : <?php echo $width ?>px;
        height : <?php echo $height ?>px;
        }

    .wvs-archive-variation-wrapper .variable-items-wrapper.squared .button-variable-item,
    .variable-items-wrapper.squared .button-variable-item {
        min-width : <?php echo $width ?>px;
        }

    .wvs-archive-variation-wrapper .button-variable-item span {
        font-size : <?php echo $font_size?>px;
        }

    .wvs-style-squared .button-variable-wrapper.rounded .button-variable-item {
        width : <?php echo $width ?>px !important;
        }

    .wvs-large-variable-wrapper .variable-item:not(.radio-variable-item) {
        width  : <?php echo $large_size_width?>px;
        height : <?php echo $large_size_height?>px;
        }

    .wvs-style-squared .wvs-large-variable-wrapper .button-variable-item {
        min-width : <?php echo $large_size_width?>px;
        }

    .wvs-large-variable-wrapper .button-variable-item span {
        font-size : <?php echo $large_size_font_size?>px;
        }

    .wvs-style-squared .button-variable-wrapper.rounded.wvs-large-variable-wrapper .button-variable-item {
        width : <?php echo $large_size_width?>px !important;
        }

    .woo-variation-swatches .variable-items-wrapper .variable-item:not(.radio-variable-item) {
        box-shadow : 0 0 0 <?php echo $border_size?>px <?php echo $border_color?> !important;
        }

    .woo-variation-swatches .variable-items-wrapper .button-variable-item span,
    .woo-variation-swatches .variable-items-wrapper .radio-variable-item label,
    .woo-variation-swatches .wvs-archive-variation-wrapper .reset_variations a {
        color : <?php echo $text_color?> !important;
        }

    .woo-variation-swatches .variable-items-wrapper .variable-item:not(.radio-variable-item) {
        background-color : <?php echo $background_color?> !important;
        }

    .woo-variation-swatches .variable-items-wrapper .button-variable-item.selected span,
    .woo-variation-swatches .variable-items-wrapper .radio-variable-item.selected label {
        color : <?php echo $selected_text_color?> !important;
        }

    .woo-variation-swatches .variable-items-wrapper .variable-item:not(.radio-variable-item).selected {
        background-color : <?php echo $selected_background_color?> !important;
        }

    .woo-variation-swatches .variable-items-wrapper .variable-item:not(.radio-variable-item).selected {
        box-shadow : 0 0 0 <?php echo $selected_border_size?>px <?php echo $selected_border_color?> !important;
        }

    .woo-variation-swatches .variable-items-wrapper .variable-item:not(.radio-variable-item):hover,
    .woo-variation-swatches .variable-items-wrapper .variable-item:not(.radio-variable-item).selected:hover {
        box-shadow : 0 0 0 <?php echo $hover_border_size?>px <?php echo $hover_border_color?> !important;
        }

    .woo-variation-swatches .variable-items-wrapper .button-variable-item:hover span,
    .woo-variation-swatches .variable-items-wrapper .button-variable-item.selected:hover span,
    .woo-variation-swatches .variable-items-wrapper .radio-variable-item:hover label,
    .woo-variation-swatches .variable-items-wrapper .radio-variable-item.selected:hover label {
        color : <?php echo $hover_text_color?> !important;
        }

    .woo-variation-swatches .variable-items-wrapper .variable-item:not(.radio-variable-item):hover,
    .woo-variation-swatches .variable-items-wrapper .variable-item:not(.radio-variable-item).selected:hover {
        background-color : <?php echo $hover_background_color?> !important;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: There is no WordPress Variation plugin, please clarify the exact name of the plugin you're using.

Comment: I have pro version of Variation Swatches for WooCommerce